# Listening or observing Command Line Execution

Tags: command-line, java-8, runtime.exec, listen

I have some code that passes commands to the command line from my java application, for example compile a latex file. Is there a way for me to listen to the result of passing the command, whether it succeeded or not?

Comment: yea that is eventually the goal.  if you pass a file with incorrect code it won't compile.  so i would to let the user know that a certain file didn't work. the use case is batch compiling latex files from a java application.

Comment: The commands I am sending to the command line work just fine, it is just that I want to detect if they were executed successfully or not in the case of a file that has incorrect content.

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.  (I think you'll find the answer amongst those recommendations.)

Comment: thanks this is very helpful.  it should address my question.  why don't you add an answer to the question so that i accept it.